# alleging defamation in a UK court

Tags: united-kingdom, defamation

The term ‘defamation’ describes an untrue statement that’s been presented as fact and causes harm to the character of the person it describes. If someone’s reputation is damaged because of a false statement, this statement will be considered defamatory.

Should an opinion be considered an accusation, and be untrue, this still defames the person in question.

Does this mean that if A alleges B defamed him, if a judge decides that A is wrong, does that mean A has defamed B?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The term "defamation" describes an untrue statement that’s been presented as fact and causes harm to the character of the person it describes.

In some jurisdictions an admittedly true statement can still be defamatory. See [Can true statements or statements of opnion be libel or defamation in any country?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/74710/can-true-statements-or-statements-of-opnion-be-libel-or-defamation-in-any-countr)

If A claimed that B defamed A, but a court rules that there was no defamation, this **might** make A's statement legally false. But it will not be defamatory unless it also harms B's reputation.  Statements made in court, and in legal filings, have [absolute privilege](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/absolute_privilege) and may not the be basis of a defamation action. Public statements by A accusing B of defamation might be the basis of such an action.